# iOS: Push Notifications only work in Development, not Ad Hoc

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've had development Push Notifications working fine for a while now, and the app currently is undergoing testing with TestFlight. The test distribution works fine, but it doesn't seem like the notifications are being sent, I'm using the `APNS` gem with Rails to manage the connection and pushing the device token to the database after it's available in the App Delegate. I've verified that it's connecting to the correct gateway and that the code is set to use the correct `pem` file, but still nothing. If I rebuild it within XCode onto my device in development mode, and push from the development server it's fine.

Comment: You stated that you are `pushing the device token to the database after it's available in the App Delegate` If you are switching environments you should see that device's token value change. Dev and Prod Tokens will be different across environments for the same device.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that but it also seems like it's not pushing correctly. Possibly it's not because I'm pushing to an invalid device token as well, so I'm going to clean the development tokens.